# Best option for a custom package builder?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

On my website id like to make a package builder to allow customer to build a package that best suits their requirements. When the customer clicks the build button it calculates the price of their custom package.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Store each item with an individual price, have some checkboxes, add up the total at the end. You'll need to at least attempt something if you want any *actual* help with this :)

Answer (score 0):

You should look into Javascript functions. You cannot achieve this by only using HTML, you could use PHP for most of the functionality but i recommend using Javascript to actually do the math on your page without having to make the user refresh. Also by using Javascript you can have functions for adding certain HTMl elemnts on the page. A good piece of javascript code i use is below, and i use it all the time to add elements on the page.

```
    container.append('<input type="text" name="elementname">');
```